# Angular ng-if flickering on $scope update interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a factory that combines 2 GET requests and should return it in to the $scope. Everything works fine until i added an ng-if. With the ng-if i need to decide which icon or style i need to apply. When i am using the ng-if, the icon flickers on every update.(tried ng-class and ng-switch etc. as well, all have the same issue) Without using ng-if, its not having issues at all.

Here's my code:

The factory

```
 app.factory('allDevices', function($http, CONFIG, $localStorage) {

 var obj = {};
  obj.list = function(zoneId){

      return $http.get('http://'+CONFIG.homey_ip + '/api/manager/devices/?zone='+zoneId, CONFIG.httpconfig).then(function(response){
          this.devices = response.data.result;
          var itemsProcessed = 0;
          return angular.forEach(this.devices, function(value, key, array) {
                                   //store data of 1st call in this.userDetails
          return $http.get('http://'+CONFIG.homey_ip + '/api/device/'+value.id, CONFIG.httpconfig).then(function(response){
              this.devices[key].state = response.data.result;
              itemsProcessed++;
              if(itemsProcessed === array.length) {

                  return this.devices;
              }
          })

        })
      })
  }
 return obj;
});
```

The controller

```
    // Set interval
$scope.intervalFunction = function(){
  timer = $timeout(function() {

    //Get alldevices within the default zone and push to frontend.
    allDevices.list($scope.$storage.defaultZone).then(function(response){
        $scope.devicelist = response;


    });
    $scope.intervalFunction();
  }, 1000)
};

// Kick off the interval
$scope.intervalFunction();
```

The (current) html, since i tried several ways.

```
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div style="" class="col-sm-2 light" ng-repeat="device in devicelist track by device.id" ng-if="device.class == 'light' || device.class == 'socket'">
              <div ng-if="device.state.onoff == false"  hm-tap="tap(device.id, true)" id="device-light" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:5px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);background-size: cover;-webkit-mask-size: contain;-webkit-mask-position: center center;-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;width:100%;height:50px;-webkit-mask-image: url(http://192.168.2.72{{device.icon}});"> </div>
              <div ng-if="device.state.onoff == true"  hm-tap="tap(device.id, false)" id="device-light" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:5px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);background-size: cover;-webkit-mask-size: contain;-webkit-mask-position: center center;-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;width:100%;height:50px;-webkit-mask-image: url(http://192.168.2.72{{device.icon}});"> </div>
              <span class="devicename">{{device.name}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to
>   bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this
>   case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope
>   will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Reason is that `ng-if` create child `$scope`, easy way to fix it can be to use `ng-show` instead because it basicly just  shown
or hidden the element by removing or adding the ng-hide CSS class onto the
element.

Comment: Well, seen an error in my first post. But tried ng-show as well with the same result. (ng-hide, ng-class etc.)

Should have tested this before, but it seems it isn't the issue with ng-if. When i output {{device.state.onoff}} it blinks the value as well.